# PostgreSQL Monthly/Daily Database growth

Tags: postgresql, report, information-schema

My goal is to generate a report showing the number of records saved each day/month in a PostgreSQL database under a specific schema.

So far i have something simiilar byt with size (MB) not count and with overal sum

```
SELECT
     table_schema || '.' || table_name AS table_full_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"')) AS size
FROM information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY
    pg_total_relation_size('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') DESC;
```

[image]

Is there any solution to generate such report:

| TABLE NAME | count | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 312 | 30-03-2023 |
| foo | 111 | 29-03-2023 |
| bar | 312 | 30-03-2023 |
| bar | 344 | 29-03-2023 |

Comment: Are you looking for snapshots saying how many records were in the table at a given time, or trying to measure all traffic? If it's snapshots, you won't spot tables that inflate after the snapshot and deflate before the next snapshot, and the other way around. If it's all traffic, you could use [`pg_recvlogical`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrecvlogical.html), tap into the [logical streaming replication protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) and plot the actual, real-time curves based on inserts and deletes taking place.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to get approximate counts (maintained by [stuff like `vacuum analyze` statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html)), then you could use such a query:

```sql
create view table_stat as 
select format('%I.%I', n.nspname, c.relname) "table name",
  reltuples "count",
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(c.oid)) "size",
  now()::date "date"
from pg_class c
join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid 
where n.nspname = 'public' 
and c.relkind  in ('r', 'm', 'p')
order by 3 desc;
```

then create a table **once** and insert first batch:

```sql
create table stat_history as select * from table_stat;
```

Then in a cron or something, to append new data:

```sql
insert into stat_history select * from table_stat;
```

Then, the final query to display results:

```sql
select * from stat_history -- where "whatever you want";
```

> Note the usage of `format('%I')` or `quote_ident()` to always get the correct escaping of double quotes.

Otherwise, you will need to use dynamic queries, using plpgsql stuff like:

- `return query execute`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4
- `execute format('…')` as exemplified in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: thank you! Now i have count per each table but how to group it by month/day?

Comment: Ah sorry, indeed it didn't solve the historisation problem. For that you would need to store the result of this query in a `stats_history` table  regularly (using a cron or something) and display from this table.

Comment: see my edited answer for a possible solution

Comment: looks good but how about when is to late to create such stat_history table? any build in solution for that?

Comment: nothing in postgres core that I'm aware of, no. There might be off-the-shelf solutions out there that track table size and cardinality history like https://pgdash.io/

Comment: some extension just came out that seems to do exactly what you want: https://github.com/vyruss/pg_statviz

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`pg_stat_all_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) system view:

```sql
create table test as select 1 AS a;

select n_tup_ins,n_tup_upd,n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd,n_live_tup,n_dead_tup 
from pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname='public' and relname='test';
-- n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del | n_tup_hot_upd | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup
-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------
--         1 |         0 |         0 |             0 |          1 |          0

insert into test select 2; 
insert into test select 3; 
delete from test where a=1; 
update test set a=5 where a=2;

select n_tup_ins,n_tup_upd,n_tup_del,n_tup_hot_upd,n_live_tup,n_dead_tup 
from pg_stat_all_tables where schemaname='public' and relname='test';
-- n_tup_ins | n_tup_upd | n_tup_del | n_tup_hot_upd | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup
-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+------------
--         3 |         1 |         1 |             1 |          2 |          2
```

You can take snapshots of this view daily using `cron` or `pg_cron` to monitor not only the estimated number of rows but also traffic leading to that number.

To see all that traffic live, you can tap into the [logical streaming replication protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) using [`pg_recvlogical`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrecvlogical.html).